# How to execute different queries to DB using something similar to addBatch() but using various preparedStatements

Tags: java, jdbc

If i need to execute many idential queries using only different variables I can use addBatch():

```
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_ELEMENT);
        for (String json : jsonObjects) {
            preparedStatement.setString(ELEMENT_ID, json);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
```

I have two queries:

```
final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE table_name"  
final String DELETE_FROM_ALL_TABLES = "DELETE FROM all_tables WHERE name = table_name"
```

I want to address to my DB only one time.
How can I do It?

Comment: 1) Those are not *queries*, they are *statements*. A `SELECT` statement is a query. A `DELETE` statement is not. --- 2) To batch multiple disparate statements, use `Statement`, not `PreparedStatement`, though I don't know why you would bother with those kind of statements, since they aren't fast enough to benefit much from batching.

Comment: And what should I choose in this case? I am writting REST app and I'm concerned that other thread could get wrong data. Thread1 -> DROP_TABLE table, Thread2 - SELECT table names from table_for_tables, Thread1 -> DELETE data about table from table_for_tables

Comment: How is sending both statements together a fix for that? Thread 2 can do that anyway.

Comment: Could you advice something in this situation?

Comment: Advice on what? If you have a problem with multi-threaded concurrency, write a new question asking about it.